# Cannont set property 'Name' of null map

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, map

I want to fill a Map the name as key and value as value of each input

cmp

```
    <aura:attribute name="mapDataCible" type="Map" access="global"/>
```

Js

```
//i get all input
    const myInput = component.find('input'); 
    let inp = (myInput.length == null) ? [myInput] : myInput;

 //i display name and value for each input IT'S WORk
    inp.forEach(input => console.log('name =' + input.get('v.name')));
    inp.forEach(input => console.log('value =' + input.get('v.value')));

    // MAP
    var mapDataCible = component.get("v.mapDataCible");
    inp.forEach(input => mapDataCible[input.get('v.name')] = input.get('v.value'));
```

i have error

```
    Cannont set property 'Name' of null
```

Comment: Your logic of `myInput.length == null` is flawed because `.length` will never return `null`. Because JavaScript is truthy, you can simply check `myInput.length`. This will return `true` if it has any length (above zero) and `false` if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

`mapDataCible` is declared but not initialised. Initialise it directly in attribute as below:

```
<aura:attribute name="mapDataCible" type="Map" default="{}" access="global"/>
```

`{}` is empty map.